# VS Code Vim Plugin: In command mode, the s and S key commands don't do anything

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I've installed `vscodevim.vim` plugin (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) to Visual Studio Code running on OS X. I have the `setting.json` that I've pasted below.

For the most part everything is working. However, in command mode the `s` and `S` key commands don't do anything. I expect that when I press `s` in command mode, the character under my cursor should be deleted and then I should be in insert mode at the cursor location. But currently it's not doing anything.

I don't see anything in my settings that should cause this. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

settings.json

```
{
  "vim.easymotion": true,
  "vim.sneak": true,
  "vim.incsearch": true,
  "vim.useSystemClipboard": true,
  "vim.useCtrlKeys": true,
  "vim.hlsearch": true,
  "vim.insertModeKeyBindings": [
    {
      "before": ["j", "j"],
      "after": ["<Esc>"]
    }
  ],
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
      "before": ["<leader>", "d"],
      "after": ["d", "d"]
    },
    {
      "before": ["<C-n>"],
      "commands": [":nohl"]
    }
  ],
  "vim.leader": "<space>",
  "vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-a>": false,
    "<C-f>": false
  },
  "window.zoomLevel": 0,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.detectIndentation": false,
  "editor.dragAndDrop": false
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the repo. I believe they are same extension, the repo and official one you linked. I installed it through the in-app VS Code plugin management system. https://github.com/brandonbloom/vscode-vim

Comment: I believe I have the official one. My original question is perhaps incorrect. I installed via this link https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim

Comment: According to their Roadmap, this has been implemented. I'd file an issue on their Github

Comment: @rfkortekaas under changing text i see both `s` and `S` which do what the OP is asking for.

Comment: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/ROADMAP.md perhaps its out of date

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I see now which commands you are referring to. You are right they should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the `"vim.sneak": true` that is causing this, as sneak remaps s and S.